# how to check if http authorization headers are set in url

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet to download the file, which is invoked when the URL is clicked. I have to verify if the client has set the authorisation headers (username/password) while calling this URL. If the headers are set then only the file should download or else some suitable HTTP status code is sent. Is there any method where can I check if the headers are present and validate them in java.

Comment: check this http://crunchify.com/simple-way-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/

Comment: Hmmm... tricky... what about [HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I am able to retrieve the header field by request.getHeader(String name). How can i test it on browser. Because when i open the URL in a browser, i will not be able to set the header field for a servlet. Even through POSTMAN, i m not able to do.

Comment: How can i call the doGet method of servlet from java application?

Answer (score -1):

for servlets:

```
        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/saveEmployee");
        URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
```

but 
if you are using REST web services then you can use `@HeaderParam("authorization") String authString` from `package import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;` in request landing method and later split `String[] authourizatonParts = authString.split("\\s+");`

I hope it will help you.